# Display text and pictures from database with SELECT and add unique link to each row?

Tags: php, sql, select

I have a database of hotels, each with latitude, longitude, id, name and picture. Actually only the path is in the database. Anyway, I have a select function which selects all the hotels in the database which are in range of 10 kilometers from a specific point I chose.

The function goes well, it retrieves me the hotels in 10 kilometers range but I want to put each result an individual link to their own web page. I mean : after the select function I get 1 result: hotel A with its picture and I want that when the user clicks on the picture or name he's taken to the hotel A `s page.

I know it can be done, I've seen it somewhere.

EDIT : my database looks like this : id, name, latitude, longitude, path(for pictures), description.

for each result that displays (hotel) i want to display a diferent link. hotel A - link for hotel A , hotel B-link for hotel B. get it? thanks !

Comment: Is the URL of the hotel stored in the database? If not, how do you expect to be able to grab it with a SELECT ?

Comment: add a "link" field to your database and that will get pulled out when you pull the record? We need to see some code to be able to help you.

Comment: Where's the link stored? how's the database (relevant) schema?

Comment: i tried to store the URL. nothing. my database looks like this: id, name, latitude, longitude, path(for pictures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the hotel's URL in the database, otherwise the best you can hope for is to provide a link to a Google SERP with the hotel name as the search parameter.

Comment: i dont know what google SERP stands for. i stored the hotel`s URL in the database and after SELECT it displays it just text .. be more specific please. and another ideea of mine to run by you. u heard about google store locator. can i use it but also retrieve the results in list just how i want them, not on map ? and if i could search the coordonates ( latitude and longitude ) not by addrese or postal code like in the original google store locator. thanks !

Comment: `be more specific please` - funny

Comment: Sorry - SERP = Search Engine Result Page. If you go to http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hilton, what you see is a SERP.

If you have stored the hotel's URL in the database and it returns it as text, all you need to do is put that text in an `<a>` tag. For example:

`<a href="this-is-where-you-would-put-the-link"><img src="hotel_image.jpg" alt="Hotel Name" /></a>`.

Comment: u dont understand. for hotel A i want link /hotelA.html , for hotel B i want /hotelB.html. for each result that displays, hotel, i want a diferent link

Comment: From what you are saying, it sounds as if you want to link to a page where the hotel is used as part of a query. So for example you have a page named hotel-details.php and on that page you would display all the information for a hotel, but that information would be pulled in dynamically from the database. Am I right so far?

Comment: u were right all along. i wasnt thinking clearly ! <a href=".$row['descriere']."><img src=\"". $row['poze'] ."\" alt=\"\"  /></a> and it returns me the picture of the hotel and also with the link . THANK YOU !

Comment: i succeded with puting link on the picture. but i want also on the "comments" ( it s text ) . i tried  echo "<a href=".$row['link'].">"$row['descriere']</a>"; and it throws me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\SITE\index5.php on line 45 - EDIT: never mid. i dit it. it was a quote in extra. php sux :(

Answer (score 0):

You're only part way to your desired solution: You have a database - great! :) That's the first step.

You now need to build a web site using a server-side programming language like C#/VB.NET, PHP, Ruby, Java, etc. Your website will contain some server-side code that executes whenever the page is accessed and which queries your database for your list of hotels and generates the necessary HTML to send back to the requesting browser.

I suggest you start here:

1. Buy and study [Head First HTML](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/) or [Head First HTML5](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml5prog/) to understand how HTML works.
2. Buy and study a book that explains how to write the server-side code using your platform of choice (e.g. ASP.NET/MVC using C#/VB.NET, Ruby on Rails, PHP, etc.)

HTH.

Comment: i can manage php and java , but vb.net ? sounds complicated.